# How to show block below fixed container with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please someone help me out on this I got stuck in my code. I'm putting my code complete below please have a look and please try to provide better solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lte IE 7]><html id="ie" class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html id="ie8" class="no-js lt-ie10 lt-ie9" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html id="ie9" class="no-js lt-ie10" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html lang="en" class="no-js" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com">
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css" /> -->
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:400,100,200,300,500,600,700,800,900|Open+Sans:400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <style type="text/css">
        body.ticketDetail {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            color: #292929;
            font: 400 14px "Exo",sans-serif;
        }
        .fixed-container {
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
        }
        .main-container {
            padding: 85px 30px 100px;
            background: none;
        }
        .toggle-wrap {
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 9;
            box-shadow: 3px 0px 5px #000;
            height: 59px;
        }
        .toggle-wrap {
            width: 100%;
            background: #f3f3f3;
            background: rgba(243,243,243,0.8);
            filter: alpha(opacity=80);
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=80);
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=80)";
        }
        .container-right>div {
            height: 175px;
            border-left: 13px solid #bbc3c6;
            background: #f4f4f4;
            margin: 0 0 8px;
            -webkit-transition: transform .35s ease-in-out, background 0.8s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: transform .35s ease-in-out, background 0.8s ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: transform .35s ease-in-out, background 0.8s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: transform .35s ease-in-out, background 0.8s ease-in-out;
            transition: transform .35s ease-in-out, background 0.8s ease-in-out;
        }
        .e-stand-b {
            border-left: 13px solid #f39c11 !important;
        }
        .e-stand-a {
            border-left: 13px solid #f1c40f !important;
        }
        .n-stand-a {
            border-left: 13px solid #3497db !important;
        }
        .n-stand-b {
            border-left: 13px solid #297fb8 !important;
        }
        .s-stand-a {
            border-left: 13px solid #dae0e0 !important;
        }
        .w-stand-a {
            border-left: 13px solid #e74b3c !important;
        }
        .w-stand-b {
            border-left: 13px solid #c1392b !important;
        }
        .container-right>div:before {
            content: '';
            display: table;
        }
        .container-right>div:after {
            content: '';
            display: table;
            clear: both;
        }
        .container-right>div:hover {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.03);
            -moz-transform: scale(1.03);
            -ms-transform: scale(1.03);
            -o-transform: scale(1.03);
            transform: scale(1.03);
            background: #000;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            filter: alpha(opacity=50);
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50);
            -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50)";
        }
        .main-container .container-fluid {
            padding: 0;
            position: relative;
        }
        .container-right-column {
            float: right;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .container-right {
            margin-left: 650px;
            position: relative;
        }
        .container-left {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            background: #f4f4f4;
            text-align: center;
            width: 630px;
            margin-right: -100%;
            height: 635px;
        }
        .container-left h2 {
            color: #9C9A9A;
            font-size: 18px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            letter-spacing: 0.4px;
            margin: 35px 0 34px;
        }
        .container-left img {
            display: block;
            max-width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .container-left a {
            position: absolute;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
            outline: none;
        }
        a.e-stand-b {
            top: 14%;
            left: 12%;
            z-index: 2;
            width: 76%;
            height: 8%;
        }
        a.e-stand-a {
            top: 22%;
            left: 20%;
            z-index: 2;
            width: 60%;
            height: 8%;
        }
        a.n-stand-b {
            top: 21%;
            left: 4%;
            z-index: 2;
            width: 9%;
            height: 60%;
        }
        a.n-stand-a {
            top: 28%;
            left: 13%;
            z-index: 2;
            width: 8%;
            height: 47%;
        }
        a.s-stand-b {
            top: 21%;
            right: 4%;
            z-index: 2;
            width: 9%;
            height: 60%;
        }
        a.s-stand-a {
            top: 28%;
            right: 13%;
            z-index: 2;
            width: 8%;
            height: 47%;
        }
        a.w-stand-b {
            bottom: 10%;
            left: 12%;
            z-index: 2;
            width: 76%;
            height: 8%;
        }
        a.w-stand-a {
            bottom: 18%;
            left: 18%;
            z-index: 2;
            width: 63%;
            height: 8%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="ticketDetail">
    <div class="toggle-wrap">
    </div>
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="container-right-column">
                <div class="container-right">
                    <div class="e-stand-a">

                    </div>
                    <div class="s-stand-a">

                    </div>
                    <div class="w-stand-a">

                    </div>
                    <div class="n-stand-a">

                    </div>
                    <div class="e-stand-b">

                    </div>
                    <div class="s-stand-b">

                    </div>
                    <div class="w-stand-b">

                    </div>
                    <div class="n-stand-b">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="fixed-container">
                <div class="container-left">
                    <h2>Stadium Name</h2>
                    <img src="images/goan-stadium-img.png" alt="stadium" usemap="#Stadium" id="#Stadium" />
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="e-stand-b"></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="e-stand-a"></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="n-stand-b"></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="n-stand-a"></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="s-stand-b"></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="s-stand-a"></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="w-stand-b"></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="w-stand-a"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function checkWidth() {
            var windowSize = $(window).width();
            if (windowSize <= 765) {
                $('#fixed-container').css('position', 'initial');
            }
            if (windowSize > 765) {
                // ----------***********Ticket Detail Prepend method***********---------------
                $('a.n-stand-b, a.n-stand-a, a.e-stand-b, a.e-stand-a, a.w-stand-b, a.w-stand-a, a.s-stand-b, a.s-stand-a').click(function() {
                    $('[class*="b-"]').removeClass(function(index, className) {
                        return (className.match(/(^|\s)b-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
                    });
                    var stand_class= $(this).attr('class');
                    $('div.'+stand_class).hide().prependTo('.container-right-column .container-right').slideDown(1000);
                    $('div.'+stand_class).addClass('b-'+stand_class);
                });

                // ----------***********Ticket Detail Hover method***********---------------
                $("div.e-stand-a, div.e-stand-b, div.s-stand-a, div.s-stand-b, div.w-stand-a, div.w-stand-b, div.n-stand-a, div.n-stand-b").mouseenter(function() {
                    var stand_class= $(this).attr('class');
                    stand_class = stand_class.split(' ');
                    $(this).addClass('b-'+stand_class[0]);
                }).mouseleave(function() {
                    var stand_class= $(this).attr('class');
                    stand_class = stand_class.split(' ');
                    $(this).removeClass('b-'+stand_class[0]);
                });
                /*$('#floatingElement').followMe({ container: '.container-column-main' });*/
            }
            if (windowSize <= 765) {
                $('a.n-stand-b, a.n-stand-a, a.e-stand-b, a.e-stand-a, a.w-stand-b, a.w-stand-a, a.s-stand-b, a.s-stand-a').attr('href', '#to-top');
                // ----------***********Ticket Detail Prepend method***********---------------
                $('a.n-stand-b, a.n-stand-a, a.e-stand-b, a.e-stand-a, a.w-stand-b, a.w-stand-a, a.s-stand-b, a.s-stand-a').click(function() {
                    $('[class*="bm-"]').removeClass(function(index, className) {
                        return (className.match(/(^|\s)bm-\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
                    });
                    var stand_class= $(this).attr('class');
                    $('div.'+stand_class).hide().prependTo('.container-right-column .container-right').slideDown(1000);
                    $('div.'+stand_class).addClass('bm-'+stand_class);
                });
            }
        }
        // Execute on load
        checkWidth();
        // Bind event listener
        $(window).resize(checkWidth);

        var sliderTop = $('.container-right').height(); // header size
        console.log(sliderTop);

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            //var notAnimated = true;
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            //console.log(sliderTop + " " + scrollTop);
            if (scrollTop > 300) {
                $('#fixed-container').addClass('fixed-container');
                $('.contact-info-wrap').css('padding-top', '300px');
            }
            if (scrollTop > sliderTop) {
                $('#fixed-container').removeClass('fixed-container');
                $('.contact-info-wrap').css('padding-top', '50px');
            }
            if (scrollTop < 300) {
                $('#fixed-container').removeClass('fixed-container');
                $('.contact-info-wrap').css('padding-top', '50px');
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Right now when I click on the left side stadium anyone of block so accordingly in the right side column it is sliding down at the top of the right container.

And after scrolling down the page I make the left container position fixed and right container scroll-able. And clicking on any stadium block the right container blocks showing on top of container only.

But what I really want that when I scroll down and then click on the left container stadium block, the right container blocks should be shown in visible window not at the top of the right container.

Please someone help me out it's really needy... And please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: You can copy and paste above code in the editor, so you can come to know what I really want.

Comment: Could you update your title to be more specific? Also, please reduce your code down to the actual problem. At the moment this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Please be mode specific and add some fiddle...

Comment: Hello Sir, sorry for the late reply .. her is the fiddle link please find the below: https://jsfiddle.net/oz2k1xav/2/